# VS.Net Pro 2015 Error al Presionar F5

Tags: c#

estoy utilizando Visual Studio Profesional 2015 (Update 3) para el desarrollo de aplicaciones. El problema esta en que cuando presiono F5, para iniciar la depuración, el IDE muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> **No se puede completar la operación**

Lo más extraño es que si acepto el mensaje e inicio la depuración nuevamente, entonces si lo hace bien. Esto ocurre cada vez que detengo la depuración, hago algunas modificaciones (o ninguna) y al presionar F5 nuevamente aparece el mensaje y así sucesivamente.

Noté que el error ocurre cuando:

> 1> Operación Compilar iniciada: proyecto: [nombre_proy], configuración: Debug x86
>
> 1> [nombre_proy] -> \\ruta_proyecto\nomb_proy\bin\Debug\nomb_proy.exe
>
> Compilar: 1 correctos, 0 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos

Al aparecer la tercer línea en la ventana de salida (Output).
Cabe mencionar que esto tiene un par de días, antes no pasaba eso. No he instalado absolutamente nada.

Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo, será de gran ayuda y le agradezco desde antes. Gracias.

Comment: He probado cerrar el IDE de VS, pero continua igual. Me di cuenta que el problema esta en el proyecto, pues abrí otro y no tuve problema alguno. No se si haya influido cambiar la ruta de la solución, de un directorio local a una de red.

Comment: Javier, de pronto tiene archivos temporales. ¿En las propiedades del proyecto tiene que el ejecutable se genere en alguna carpeta específica?

Comment: En las propiedades del proyecto, la "Ruta de acceso de salida" es: bin\Debug\

Comment: Quise intentar la solución que citas aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079466/visual-studio-popup-the-operation-could-not-be-completed/9130257#9130257, pero me di cuenta que en el path donde esta el archivo .sln hay dos archivos .suo y en ".vs\nombre_proy\v14\" hay otro (sin nombre).

Comment: porque en el comentario usas \\ruta_proyecto, tienes el desarrollo en una ruta de red ? s es asi eso es un problema, mueve el codigo a una carpeta local de tu pc

Comment: Hola Leandro. Tengo la mayoría de los proyectos en una carpeta compartida en un servidor. Todos funcionan de maravilla, excepto éste. Intente borrar los archivos .suo pero sigue igual.

Comment: ¿También te sucede si abres el visual como administrador?

Comment: Hola shop350, como Administrador no muestra ese mensaje... Pero entonces, qué estará ocurriendo?, pues antes no era necesario.

Comment: shop350, canté victoria antes de tiempo, como Administrador no muestra el mensaje en la primera depuración, en las siguientes sí.